# R equivalent of array_pop for merging two character dataframes?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm stumped by the lack of an equivalent of array pop in R dataframes. I've checked dplyr and there's nothing quite like it.

Here's dataframe 1, which is nothing more than words, a numeric, and a group word. The goal is to match, in order, the questions from dataframe 2 to the content of dataframe 1, stopping when there are no more matches.

```
DF1
Word    Volume    Group
tuna    100    fish
tuna fish    90    fish
chicken eggs    90    eggs
ostrich eggs    80    eggs

DF2
Group_Word    Question
fish    how big is a tuna fish?
fish    what's the best tasting tuna fish?
eggs    how many eggs does a chicken lay per day?
eggs    how to poach eggs?
eggs    do eggs need to be refrigerated?
beef    what's the best flavor of beef
```

dplyr's left_join would seem to be the logical choice, but it doesn't work, instead spitting out something that looks more like a full join.

```
blendeddf <- left_join(DF1,DF2, by =c("Group" = "Group_Word"))
```

This is the expected/intended result:

```
DF1
Word    Volume    Group
tuna    100    fish    how big is a tuna fish?
tuna fish    90    fish    what's the best tasting tuna fish?
chicken eggs    90    eggs    how many eggs does a chicken lay per day?
ostrich eggs    80    eggs    how to poach eggs?
```

This is the actual result:

```
Word Volume Group                                  Question
1          tuna    100  fish                   how big is a tuna fish?
2          tuna    100  fish        what's the best tasting tuna fish?
3     tuna fish     90  fish                   how big is a tuna fish?
4     tuna fish     90  fish        what's the best tasting tuna fish?
5  chicken eggs     90  eggs how many eggs does a chicken lay per day?
6  chicken eggs     90  eggs                        how to poach eggs?
7  chicken eggs     90  eggs          do eggs need to be refrigerated?
8  ostrich eggs     80  eggs how many eggs does a chicken lay per day?
9  ostrich eggs     80  eggs                        how to poach eggs?
10 ostrich eggs     80  eggs          do eggs need to be refrigerated?
```

If I were doing this in PHP, it'd be array_match and then array_pop to remove items (to avoid repetition) but I have no idea how to accomplish this in R. What should I be doing?

DPUTted code:

```
structure(list(Word = c("tuna", "tuna fish", "chicken eggs", 
"ostrich eggs"), Volume = c(100L, 90L, 90L, 80L), Group = c("fish", 
"fish", "eggs", "eggs")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
structure(list(Group_Word = c("fish", "fish", "eggs", "eggs", 
"eggs", "beef"), Question = c("how big is a tuna fish?", "what's the best tasting tuna fish?", 
"how many eggs does a chicken lay per day?", "how to poach eggs?", 
"do eggs need to be refrigerated?", "what's the best flavor of beef"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Can you  include your example data (`DF1` and `DF2`) using `dput`? It's hard to get it imported into R to test out solutions at present

Comment: Done! Output in the original post.

Comment: Also updated to show the actual results.

Comment: I'm a bit confused; `left_join` does exactly what you would expect. For example for one `fish` in `DF1` there are 2 `fish` rows in `DF2`. What's the rule for associating `"how big is a tuna fish?"` with the first row of `DF1`, and `"what's the best tasting tuna fish?"` with the second row of `DF1`? You join on `Group` only.

Comment: @MauritsEvers I'm unclear why left join is adding rows. It should be all X and only Y that match, not creating duplicates of X to match all Y that match X. The intended complete DF1 should look like the original (4 rows) with the questions appended.

Comment: @ChristopherPenn Yes I understand your expected output; but that's not how `left_join` works (not here in `dplyr` nor in `SQL` or `pandas` for that matter). I'm unclear how you decide on which row to join (see my previous comment). Joining by `Group` will give you two potential `fish` rows for the first row of `DF1`. Which one do you pick? Ditto for row 2.

Comment: [continued] As Marius' shows in his answer below, you will need *another* key to resolve ambiguities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get your expected results by adding an extra column marking the number in each group:

```
DF1 = DF1 %>%
    group_by(Group) %>%
    mutate(GroupNum = 1:n())
DF2 = DF2 %>%
    group_by(Group_Word) %>%
    mutate(GroupNum = 1:n())

DF1 %>%
    left_join(DF2, by = c("Group" = "Group_Word", "GroupNum"))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   Group [2]
  Word         Volume Group GroupNum Question                                 
  <chr>         <int> <chr>    <int> <chr>                                    
1 tuna            100 fish         1 how big is a tuna fish?                  
2 tuna fish        90 fish         2 what's the best tasting tuna fish?       
3 chicken eggs     90 eggs         1 how many eggs does a chicken lay per day?
4 ostrich eggs     80 eggs         2 how to poach eggs?
```

Comment: Thank you! That makes much more sense. I was thinking either that, or do a left join prior to building the two tables.